# In (Py)Spark, output operations executed on a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

Is it possible to output the operations that will be executed on a Spark DataFrame when e.g. `show` is called?

Background: at one point in the sequence of operations we see changes on our DataFrame that we cannot explain. In one step the data looks fine, in the next it has changed in a way that cannot be directly explained by the operations we're seeing.

```py
df = some_spark_operation1(df)
df.show()  # data in column 'x' is fine
df = some_spark_operation2(df)
df.show()  # data in column 'x' is broken, but operation2 is not expected to alter 'x' in any way
```

We need to find out why 'x' is changed in between.

Comment: When you add `some_spark_operation2`, any element from it can be moved upstream, if you don't save your  result after `some_spark_operation1`. Sometimes this unexpectedly changes the result. Try saving the intermediate result and providing the saved result as a new input to `some_spark_operation2`.

Answer (score 0):

The changes in `x` would be traced back from the signature of the `some_spark_operation2` isnt it , if you can deduce what the logic says , You ll have your answer

Other than this , I can think you are interested in the [Lineage](https://mallikarjuna_g.gitbooks.io/spark/content/spark-rdd-lineage.html) of the Dataframe , for which you can use - https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.toDebugString.html

Comment: That's exactly the problem. The signature/logic of `some_spark_operation2` does not indicate why 'x' is changed the way it is, or rather at all. The RDD Lineage definitely looks like a promising approach. I'll see if it helps. Thanks.